# Complex graphical layouts on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

First, I'm really a beginner in Android, so apologies if my question is a simple RTFM.

I'm trying to do a circular graphical layout (with multiple `ImageViews` rotated around a center, each having the same drawable, for now), and I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to do it. I have looked into it, and the documentation in Android is surprisingly sparse.

Right now, I'm using the `rotation`, `translationX` and `translationY` for ImageViews inside a `FrameLayout` in XML, but it doesn't scale well when you test it on different devices. I *could* make a different layout file for each device, but honestly that's a pain.

- Is there a way I can make the entire layout scale automatically? What I mean by that is, if I define the correct translation, rotations and scales for each element inside it, could the entire `FrameLayout` fill the screen "magically"?
- Can I do off-center rotations in my layout? Say, translate by the radius of the circle and rotate around the center of the circle, *not* the center of the object? Or any other chain of transformations, for that matter?
- If using XML layouts is impossible, and if I have to do that in code (which I'd like to avoid), what's the best location to do that? I would do that in the `onCreate` method, but maybe there's a better way?

Note that I do not want to create *animations*, I only want a *static layout*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to like my answer but, if you are doing complex layouts that you cannot achieve with the default view groups and widgets *and* you can't get them to scale well, then writing your own view group and extending ImageView is probably the way to go.

You then have complete control over both how the image views are positioned, taking into account the device DPI and resolution, and how the image views themselves behave.  A lot of work up front but big payback later.

The primary overrides you'll need are onMeasure() and onDraw() and of course initialisation in custom constructors.

It seems from your question that you have the skill but do come back if you need help on specfics.  onMeasure() in particular can be tricky to get your head around.

This is of course my opinion and YMMV.

Good luck.

Comment: Ah, darn. If I don't have the skill, I'll find it somewhere, but I was expecting it to be easier. I suppose it is possible, but can I, for instance, extend `FrameLayout` and add new parameters for custom transformations, or override the behavior of `layout_width` to accept percentage widths in the children of my new Layout? I don't really know where to begin, but I'll look into it anyway ;)